# Working with relations in Symfony 1?

Tags: php, symfony1

I need some help working with some relations in a small symfony application. I have the following structure:

```
Order
Customer
CustomerOrder
```

CustomerOrder has a PK, id, and i have two columns: order_id and customer_id from the Order and Customer tables. A customer can have many orders, while an order only has one customer. Inside my forms, how can i change them to reflect this?

- How to add the customer in the order form?
- How to add all the orders in the customer form?

By the way, i'm not asking how to create the schema, but how to customize the forms to match the relation behavior.

Comment: Isn't part of your problem that your schema is wrong? This is a 1 to many relationship you describe, but you have modelled it using many to many. 1 order doesn't have many customers...

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using the built in Many to Many relationships in Symfony 1? http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files there is a section on this page title "Many to Many". I suggest reading through that and you will likely see the answers to the questions you pose.

Comment: I have checked the documentation but couldn't find a practical example of the manipulation of forms using this schema.

Comment: By the way, i'm not asking how to create the schema, but how to customize the forms to match the relation behavior.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.inluck.net/Blog/Many-to-many-relations-in-embedded-form-in-Symfony-1_4 this blog post got me over to the other side when I was figuring out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are pretty simple:

> ```
> How to add the customer in the order form?
> ```

Assuming that your schema/model is constructed correctly, and if you've created your magic method __toString() in lib/model/Customer.class.php you should be able to see a select box of customers on your default order form.

> ```
> How to add all the orders in the customer form?
> ```

Its not clear what you want here. If you want to see all the orders associated with a customer on the order form, you could create a method in CustomerOrderPeer that retrieves all the order for a specific customer, sorta like this:

```
$this->CustomerOrders = CustomerOrderPeer::getOrdersByCustomer($this->Customer->getId());
```

If you call this in your action, you'll pass these objects to your forms template, where you'll be able to create a table of orders for the customer.